# Convert Adobe 3D-pdf to WebGL?

Tags: pdf, 3d, webgl

Is there a way to convert an Adobe 3D-pdf file to WebGL?
I searched the web but couldn't find a method. 
Adobe 3d pdf files have the disadvantage that they can only be viewed directly in the browser in Internet Explorer (and maybe on Safari -don't know), but if you use Firefox or Chrome, you need to download the file and open it in Acrobat. Moreover you need to activate it, sometimes adapt security settings... Whilst WebGL works directly in modern browsers.
The export to 3d pdf is from Amira.

Comment: I'm just going to guess that number of pdfs containing 3D is so small the no on really cares to implement that feature. Of course you could try [adding it to pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/3254)

Comment: Thanks for the info about pdf.js.

Comment: Actually in my work field it is a lot used feature, see for instance the work of a colleague institution as most extensive example: they made a major embryo 3D model and published it open at https://www.3dembryoatlas.com/blank , this even was published in Science. And we ourselves also use 3D pdf, the reason for my question, but it is a nuisance sometimes for all security blocks to run it. But I'm afraid to learn now that the usage in our field (anatomy) seems to be somewhat an exception...

Comment: Sorry, I should have said the percent of PDFs with 3D in them is probably 0.00000001% of the total PDFs out there. Probably a million PDFs are created every day and only a few have 3D in them. That said, if your industry needs that feature they should hire someone to add it to PDF.js to help their industry.

Comment: That I fully agree! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact possible to convert 3D PDF to WebGL.

You've got multiple options:

1. Content in 3D PDF is either u3d or prc. Use the respective library to read data and write to WebGL format.
2. Get the designed 3D model if you have access to it and skipping 3D PDF, just convert that model to WebGL.
3. Use Hoops, which is capable of this conversion.

Comment: What do you mean by respective library? you have an example?