# Convert three.js to Adobe 3D-pdf?

Tags: pdf, three.js, u3d

Is there way to convert three.hs as U3D to 3D pdf?

I want to export assembly I have as three.js to 3d pdf based on tree structure (children of children).

Is it possible?

Something opposite to [Convert Adobe 3D-pdf to WebGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791687/convert-adobe-3d-pdf-to-webgl/48650608)

Comment: There are not so many [exporters](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=exporter) in Three.js.

Comment: I'm not aware of any PDF library tools that are both free and directly support 3D. Also, I misunderstood what you have to start with. If you do not already have a U3D file or cannot create one, you will not be able to add it to a PDF.

Answer (score 2):

We have lately done some experiments ObjExporter (amended to also export the container colors). By the same method you can also import STL Files, but then we have not found a way to transfer the colors.

The obj/stl file are then transformed to U3D files with [Meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/).

These U3D files then can be transformed with miktex/latex into 3D pdfs[(see here)](http://rainnic.altervista.org/en/content/embed-3ds-pdf-latex-u3d?language_content_entity=en). The system also can run on a server with some batch script.

Comment: but arn't there some problems with textures?

Comment: The 3D (stl, obj) purely export the geometry. As you can see in this post ( https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47950) for the colors and textures you would have to create an mtl (+ export the texture files) file in connection with the obj file, which is normally not done by the OBJExporter, therefore you would have to amend it in that respect.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: I have followed the steps given in the link provided . I've reached to a certain place but I'm facing issue with this line == {\linewidth}{\linewidth}{dissabbiatore_meshlab.u3d}\\ . Any solution for this . any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @AlokWalunj May I ask what the corresponding error message of the TEX compiler is?

Comment: Thank you for all the steps you've provided for U3D pdf . First I've exported the 3D object to JLB format so I was able to export the 3D object with color. but, I was not able to get the color of the 3D object when exported from JLB to U3D pdf . any suggestions, any help would be greatly appreciated.