# Convert - GLTF/STL/OBJ file formats to U3D file for PDF page

Tags: pdf, three.js, 3d, export, u3d

I am trying to add three.js based 3D objects to a PDF page. It seems there are no direct exporters available to do that. So I am trying to do the below thing,

1. Convert the **gltf/stl/obj** files to **U3D** files
2. Add the **.u3d file to PDF page**.

I am trying to do the below process and I am not sure whether this approach is possible. It will be a great help if there is any support available to do any one of the below conversions. Also if you know any other possible approaches, kindly update me!!

```
     Input formats      output format

        GLTF
        OBJ                U3D
        STL
       (any
       three.js supported
       3D formats)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like meshlab might help you...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650550/convert-three-js-to-adobe-3d-pdf

Comment: Thanks, @manthrax. The reason is to create a PDF page with 3D objects (PDF reports basically). I will check with meshlab features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few options available to export the three.js graphics to a PDF ( static content not a dynamic U3D assets)

**Static contents**

1. Get the rendered data from the three.js webGL renderer / canvas renderer using `toDataURL("image/jpeg")`, change the MIME type to JPG/PNG and add the resulting stream as an image to PDF ( this worked for me)

   example - https://plnkr.co/edit/Ty8BZaDcflCJH5tH?preview
2. Like the above approach we can use three.js svgrenderer to export the renderer contents into a SVG data stream, which can be added into the PDF ( textures, mesh may not be 100% reproduced)
3. The legacy API - ["threejs-pdf-renderer"](https://github.com/pacificIT/threejs-pdf-renderer) can be used to directly export the three.js animations to a PDF. We don't need any other dependencies to create the PDF. But this is a legacy API which uses legacy three.js version, lot of effort needs to be done to make the API to be compatible with the latest three.js version.

   example - https://satheeshks10.github.io/ThreejsPDFGenerator/

**Dynamic 3D contents**

We can export the three.js animations into a U3D file (no direct support is available as for now), this U3D file can be directly embedded into PDF.
example - https://tetra4d.com/pdf-samples/